# How to track the dynamic change in input field value using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an input field which is changing dynamically on some event.

```
<input name="selectedId" id="selectedId" ng-model="selectedId" type="hidden" on-change="setUrl">
```

Now I want to redirect the page to that id present in input field when ever it changes.

**My controller**:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []).
  config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when("/a1", { templateUrl: "partials/page1.html"}).
      when("/a2", { templateUrl: "partials/page2.html"}).
      otherwise( { redirectTo: "/a1" });
  });
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $location) {  
  $scope.setUrl=function($scope){
    if ($scope.selectedId) {
      alert($scope.selectedId);
    }
    else{
     alert("Out of scope"); 
    }
    //$location.path($scope.selectedId);
  };
```

Here, I am not able to put the input field value in to scope. I'm not even able to trigger `setUrl()` so that I can redirect the URL.

I'm new to AngularJS so I need to understand the concept.

Comment: Its Working for keypress event, But not for the dynamic values through javascript.

Answer (score 3):

1. You are using `on-change`. AngularJS has a `ngChange` directive. Use it.
2. Once you use ngChange also replace `setUrl` with `setUrl()`.
3. Then, remove the $scope param from `setUrl` function signature. $scope is defined inside the `MainCtrl` so it's implicitly available to all functions defined in it. You don't ned to pass it in.
4. You are using hidden input to receive the new `id` from somewhere, only to pass it on to `setUrl`function. You don't need that hidden input. Consider using AngularJS shared services, or event broadcasting, or use $scope.$watch.

Answer (score 1):

One possible to your work around is

Register a watch on input model and change location inside that watch function

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $location) {  
 $scope.$watch('selectedId',function(newvalue,oldvalue){
  $location.path(newvalue);
 }
  };

<input name="selectedId" id="selectedId" ng-model="selectedId" type="hidden" >
```

Comment: I tried it but its not working. any link. on change its not calling controller function.